# Usage of "take a/someone's life"

Tags: phrase-usage

If I say that he took his life yesterday, which means he committed suicide yesterday.

If I say that Tim took William's life yesterday, which means Tim committed murder yesterday.

But is the usage also used in this kind of sentence?

> The tsunami took one thousand lives yesterday.

Or it should be used with "away" such as:

> The tsunami took away one thousand lives yesterday.

Which is right? or we often  use the phrasal verb in another way?

The bold part of this sentence from my book is not correct?

> According to the statistics, **drunk driving took away almost one thousand lives in Taiwan last year**.

[image: page of an exercise book with part of a sentence underlined]

Comment: Shin Yi, welcome to ELL! Please take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how this site works!

Answer (score 1):

A tsunami took 1,000 lives yesterday. Without the word **away**.

**Take away** has another meaning: **My teacher took my ruler away**.

**Take lives** does not take a preposition. Take away means to remove something from a person or place. Take lives=to kill people.

In my opinion, "drunk driving took away 1,000 lives" is not really very idiomatic in English. It makes lives sound like a thing you can haul away.